# SQL Server Query performance issue with ROW_NUMBER pagination

Tags: sql-server

Could any of you please let me know why the row_number paging function is having a performance issue when using the `"HERE results.ROWNUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 50` clause (takes more than 2 mins), but runs in 5 secs when I comment the where clause which will return the entire result set, which returns about 623 records.

I see the query is using the same indexes, but some how when the where clause is used the logical reads increases exponentially for 2 tables as below, I was trying to fix this from quite some time, any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

when the where clause is used

> Table 'INTERCHANGEJDO'. Scan count 15416, logical reads 144336865, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 16, logical reads 70965478, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead

When the where clause is commented

> Table 'INTERCHANGEJDO'. Scan count 16, logical reads 18501, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

```sql
SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

WITH ALLRESULTS AS 
(
    SELECT 
        t5.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FUNCTIONALGROUPNAME DESC) ROWNUMBER 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             t0.JDOID, t0.ACCEPTCODE, t0.ACCEPTCODE824,t0.ACKDATE, t0.UTILITY, 
             t0.DIRECTION, t0.DOCUMENTREFERENCENUMBER, t3.DESCRIPTION FUNCTIONALGROUPNAME, 
             t0.INTERCHANGE_JDOID, t0.MODIFIEDBY, t0.MODIFYDATE, t0.PROCESSDATE, 
             t0.SENTDATE, t0.SETID, t0.STATUS, t0.TURNED,
             t0.PARTNER, t0.NETWORKID, t1.INTERCHANGECONTROLNUMBER, t1.TRADINGPARTNERPAIR_JDOID,
             TRANSLATIONJOBID = CASE 
                                   WHEN (t0.TRANSLATIONJOBID IS NULL OR t0.TRANSLATIONJOBID = '') 
                                      THEN t1.TRANSLATIONJOBID
                                      ELSE t0.TRANSLATIONJOBID 
                                END
         FROM  
             DOCUMENTJDO AS t0 WITH (NOLOCK) 
         INNER JOIN 
             INTERCHANGEJDO t1 ON t0.INTERCHANGE_JDOID = t1.JDOID
         INNER JOIN 
             TRADINGPARTNERPAIRJDO t3 ON t1.TRADINGPARTNERPAIR_JDOID = t3.JDOID 
         WHERE 
             t0.direction = 'I' 
             AND t0.processDate >= '2019-07-18 00:00:00'
             AND t0.processDate <= '2020-09-18 23:59:59' 
             AND (t1.TRADINGPARTNERPAIR_JDOID IN (SELECT DISTINCT vw.TPPDS_JDOID 
                                                  FROM vwEDXMain vw WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                                  WHERE (vw.levelCode LIKE '32,J4Q%') 
                                                    AND vw.TPPDS_JDOID IS NOT NULL))) AS t5
),
RESULT AS 
(
    SELECT 
        results.*, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALLRESULTS) AS TOTAL 
    FROM 
        ALLRESULTS AS results
    WHERE 
        results.ROWNUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 50
),
DOCUMENTVIEWED AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DOCUMENTID 
    FROM DOCUMENTUSERJDO WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE VIEWED = 1
),
DOCUMENTVIEWEDBYUSER AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DOCUMENTID AS DOCUMENTID_USER, USERID, VIEWED 
    FROM DOCUMENTUSERJDO
    WHERE USERID = 'com.-19422' AND VIEWED = 1
)
SELECT 
    t5.*,
    VIEWED = CASE 
                WHEN t5.DOCUMENTID_VIEWED IS NULL 
                   THEN 0 
                WHEN t6.USERID IS NULL 
                   THEN 2 
                ELSE T6.VIEWED 
             END
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         t3.*, 
         t4.DOCUMENTID AS DOCUMENTID_VIEWED 
     FROM 
         RESULT AS t3
     LEFT JOIN 
         DOCUMENTVIEWED AS t4 ON t4.DOCUMENTID = 'com.-' + ltrim(t3.JDOID)) AS t5
LEFT JOIN 
    DOCUMENTVIEWEDBYUSER AS t6 ON t6.DOCUMENTID_USER = t5.DOCUMENTID_VIEWED 
ORDER BY 
    T5.ROWNUMBER
GO

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

Comment: I *highly* recommend learning about whitespace and linebreaks; that SQL is impossible to read. The fact that the aliasing makes no sense doesn't help either: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Do also need all those `NOLOCK` hints (especially against one object that's a `VIEW`? Do you understand its implications? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: I suspect that there is a nested loop issue.  Perhaps you can remove everything except the fields and tables required to get the records required.  I find that sometimes focusing on the "keys" first makes it easier to efficiently get only the records desired.  Refining one step at a time can show what step is the issue.  This query is complicated.  The optimizer is trying to give you exactly what you are asking for, but perhaps you can ask for the same thing is less complicated way.